# Android Listview scrolling to a specific position

Tags: android

I've overrided listview scrolling behavior like this:

```
myListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                 if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {


                    }

            }

        });
```

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to scroll to nearest item position when scrolling is done. (for instance customer is scrolling down or up). I tried to use for instance mylist.SmoothScrollToPosition(), but then it scrolls one by one to the end 
I'm using Android 2.2

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Untested!

When the scroll state switches from fling/touch to idle, you can detect the first visible item in the AbsListView. Then just call `smoothScrollToPosition` on your list view.

Comment: problem is doing it this way that it goes trough whole list since smoothScroll fire onScrollStateChanged I guess, can't find way to avoid chain reaction :)

Comment: setSelection() is avoiding this, still not sure why bit it works.

Comment: Good to hear! I'm not sure why the smooth version triggers what you're seeing, I'd have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to your last visiting place using below.

```
List<Item> myListData = ...;
for(Item item : myListData){
    if(isNextItem(Item){
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListData.indexOf(item));
        break;
    }
}
```

or if you know your `position of item`, You can simply call

```
listView.smootchScrollToPosition(position);
```